Config webpack to use scss module in ReactJS
// src/Button.js
import React from "react";
import styles from "./Button.module.scss"; // Import SCSS module

const Button = () => {
  console.log("styles", styles);
  return <button>Click Me</button>; // Use the scoped class
};

export default Button;

==> i cannot use styles here, console.log styles here output: undefined
Code sample: https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/9npfdc?migrateFrom=j22xcg
Please help me to config webpack so that I can use scss module.
I'd like to use something like this: className={Styles["button"]}
Try updating webpack config without success
